# How do I get the data in the console using JS

Tags: javascript

I want to retrieve the data in the JavaScript console and put it on screen. Does anyone have experience on how do do this?

Comment: `1.` We cannot see what you are doing wrong if we don't get to see your code and `2.` This is very basic in js, you should grab your favorite browser and search for some tutorials to get started

Comment: @ChrisG I don't have the code yet because I haven't gotten a answer.

Comment: @YesDev The Gemini is showing how do log text in the console, I want to get the data

Comment: I posted a new answer on the human tab